# How to get All the elements of the entity in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, angular5

I'm sending a GET request from angular5 to spring-boot to get all the elements of the entity Contrat below  .

This is the entity :

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Contrat implements Serializable{

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private Date dateDebut ;
        private Date dateFin ;
        private boolean valid; 
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_Project")
        @JsonBackReference(value="projet-contrat")
        private Project project;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_AppUser")
        @JsonBackReference(value="appuser-contrat")
        private AppUser appUser;
}
```

This is the repository :

```
  public interface ContratRepo extends JpaRepository<Contrat,Long> {

    @Query("select from Contrat c where c.appUser = :userApp")
    public Page<Contrat> chercherContrat(@Param("userApp") AppUser userApp  
   , Pageable pageable);

   }
```

In Angular5 the console.log(data) returns this result for exemple:

```
 {id: 1, dateDebut: 1526083200000, dateFin: 1526083200000}
```

So as you can see there is not the project element (that i need in front-end) .

I want to show in angular the contrat elements plus some information of the project related to .

should i send two GET request to get the information from both entities ? 
or there is any better method ?

**Result i get in mysql database**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use one of the prime features of JPA... [query derivation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.x/reference/html/#jpa.sample-app.finders.strategies)! Like so:

```
public interface ContratRepo extends JpaRepository<Contrat,Long> {

    public Page<Contrat> findByAppUser(AppUser userApp, Pageable pageable);

}
```

And if you want the `Project`, use `@EntityGraph`:

```
public interface ContratRepo extends JpaRepository<Contrat,Long> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "project"}, type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    public Page<Contrat> findByAppUser(AppUser userApp, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for answering , I did the same as in your answer but im not getting the 'project' .

Comment: Since it sounds like you're sending it back straight to the UI, then you'll probably need to put the `LOAD` hint on it so it's fetched immeditely. See edit.

Comment: OK, what does the hibernate query look like going to the database? It sounds like there's no `Project` association in the DB for this `AppUser`

Comment: can you tell me please how to log the query ? so  i can see how it looks like .

Comment: You set the Hibernate `hibernate.show_sql` property to `true` in your `EntityManager` configuration

Comment: Result : Hibernate: select contrat0_.id as id1_3_0_, project2_.id as id1_7_1_, contrat0_.id_app_user as id_app_u5_3_0_, contrat0_.date_debut as date_deb2_3_0_, contrat0_.date_fin as date_fin3_3_0_, contrat0_.id_project as id_proje6_3_0_, contrat0_.valid as valid4_3_0_, project2_.id_app_user as id_app_u4_7_1_, project2_.description as descript2_7_1_, project2_.intitule as intitule3_7_1_ from contrat contrat0_ left outer join app_user appuser1_ on contrat0_.id_app_user=appuser1_.id left outer join project project2_ on contrat0_.id_project=project2_.id where appuser1_.id=? limit ?

Comment: Good thing is, looks like you're actually including the `Project` as part of your query (i.e. `project2_.id_app_user as id_app_u4_7_1_, project2_.description as descript2_7_1_, project2_.intitule as intitule3_7_1_`)! Bad news; it looks like the association doesn't exist for project and that's why you're not seeing it. Try running it in the DB, subsituting the question mark for appuser ID with your real value. I think you'll find you don't have the data association you're expecting!

Comment: You mean that there is no project for this user right ?

Comment: The problem is that when i send request with Get to see the projects of this user , i can get the right projects , so weird

Comment: You're saying just the serialized JSON doesn't have the `projects` element?

Comment: Indeed , i cant get this attribut in front end –

Comment: Could you check and run the same query and same parameters against the database and tell me what you get?

Comment: i have edited the post with the result i get , if you can see it again :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant run that generates hibernate query you posted earlier!